# Creating custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute leads to exception on compile

Tags: .net, wcf, code-security

I'm building a custom CodeAccessSecurityAttribute to handle authorization for my WCF services. I built class A as such:

```
public class A : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public A() : base(SecurityAction.Demand)
    {
        // Constructor Code
    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        // Permission Creation Code
    }

}
```

And on compilation it produces this error.

```
Error emitting 'A' attribute -- 'Serialized security custom attribute is 
truncated or incorrectly formed.'
```

After playing with it a little I came up with the next sample that does compile without error:

```
public class B : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute
{
    public B(SecurityAction Action) : base(Action)
    {
        // Constructor Code
    }

    public override IPermission CreatePermission()
    {
        // Permission Creation Code
    }

}
```

I know it's because the SecurityAction enum isn't directly referenced to public side of Class A, but what I can't figure out is how to make it so that I can do it the Class A method instead of the Class B.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don’t know the exact reason for the requirement, but the [MSDN documentation on CodeAccessSecurityAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.codeaccesssecurityattribute.aspx) clearly states

> Notes to Inheritors
>
> All permission attributes derived from this class must have only a single constructor that takes a SecurityAction as its only parameter.

**Amended**: The reason for this requirement is that `CodeAccessSecurityAttribute` is, from a low-level view, quite different from other custom attributes. Generally, custom attributes are stored in the compiled metadata in the `CustomAttribute` table. But the security attributes, deriving from `SecurityAttribute`, are stored separately in the `DeclSecurity` table. And this table does not contain the general data like the CustomAttribute table, this table contains the value of `Action`, the name of the attribute type, plus a set of the properties (named arguments) like in the custom attribute case. So, the compiler needs to convert a general custom attribute syntax to an entry in this metadata table, so it needs it to follow the fixed form noted above. (See also [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2010/04/21/declarative-security-and-reflection.aspx), or Partition II, section *22.11 DeclSecurity : 0x0E* of the *Common Language Infrastructure (CLI)* standard.)

Comment: I'll mark this as the answer for now, but what I don't understand is that if I'm forcing the SecurityAction to be one value when calling back down to the base class, why does it care about the instantiating class?

Comment: @thaBadDawg: The thing is, you might try to add the required parameter to the constructor, but ignoring it and passing a constant to `base()`. However, it seems not to work, anyway, the CAS attributes are not evaluated the “classical” way, it seems.

Comment: I'll always be using "Demand".  It's annoying that I have to specify it.  Oh well, at least it's an enum.

Answer (score 3):

If you supply the constructor with a default value you don't have to specify it in the attribute.

```
public class B : CodeAccessSecurityAttribute 
{ 
    public B(SecurityAction Action = SecurityAction.Demand) : base(Action) 
    { 
        // Constructor Code 
    } 

    public override IPermission CreatePermission() 
    { 
        // Permission Creation Code 
    } 
}
```